# Returns a list with only 20 entries. Does not go beyond that

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
#importing the libraries
import urllib.request as urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#getting the page url
quote_page="https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-advice-you-can-give-to-a-junior-programmer"

page=urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

#parsing the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "AnswerListDiv"})

#finding all  the tags in the page
ans=name_box.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "u-serif-font-main--large"},recursive=True)

#separating the answers into lists
for i in range(0, len(ans), 100):
    chunk = ans[i:i+100]

#extracting all the answers and putting into a list 
finalans=[]
l=0
for i in chunk:
    stri=chunk[l]
    finalans.append(stri.text)
    l+=1
    continue

final_string = '\n'.join(finalans)

#final output
print(final_string)
```

I am not able to get more than 20 entries into this list. What is wrong with this code? (I am a beginner and I have used some references to write this program)
Edit: I have added the URL  I want to scrape.

Comment: Why are you using `continue` in your loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `chunk = ans[i:i+100]` line?  It looks like you're ignoring everything before the last 100 elements of `ans`

Comment: If possible can you share the url that you're trying to scrape?

Comment: `finalans=[]` and friends should be indented to be in the for loop so that chunks are processed as they are created instead of discarded. ... leading to the next question, why do chunks in the first place? Its already all in memory.

Comment: In the chunk part, I am trying to repeat the code for at least for100 entries.But "ans" variable does not even go beyond 20.

Comment: To get beyond 20 items you need to use any browser simulatior like `selenium` cause they are being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You try to break `ans` into smaller chunks, but notice that each iteration of this loop discards the previous content of `chunks` so you loose all but the last chunk of data.

```
#separating the answers into lists
for i in range(0, len(ans), 100):
    chunk = ans[i:i+100]    # overwrites previous chunk
```

This is why you only get 20 items in the list... its only the final chunk. Since you want `final_string` to hold all of the text nodes, there is no need to chunk and I just removed it.

Next, and this is just tightening up the code, you don't need to both iterate the values of the list and track an index just to get the same value you are indexing. Working on `ans` because we are no longer chunking,

```
finalans=[]
l=0
for i in ans:
    stri=ans[l]
    finalans.append(stri.text)
    l+=1
    continue
```

becomes

```
finalans=[]
for item in ans:
    finalans.append(item.text)
```

or more susinctly

```
finalans = [item.text for item in ans]
```

So the program is

```
#importing the libraries
import urllib.request as urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#getting the page url
quote_page="https:abcdef.com"

page=urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

#parsing the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "AnswerListDiv"})

#finding all  the tags in the page
ans=name_box.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "u-serif-font-main--large"},recursive=True)

#extracting all the answers and putting into a list 
finalans = [item.text for item in ans]

final_string = '\n'.join(finalans)

#final output
print(final_string)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the code still does not get beyond 20.

Comment: Thanks for posting the url! I was able to test to see that you get two lists: `name_box` and `ans`. `name_box` has 26 values but you don't use it further in processing. `ans` has 20 values and you use it to build `finalans`, which is also 20 values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing `name_box` values out. But `ans` is derived from `name_box`. Wouldn't it have the same values?

The goal of the program is to get all the answers of that particular quora page.The page has over 100 answers. So 26 from the `name_box` is still incorrect. What does the program lack?